# Is there a way to have a radio group be laid out horizontally?

Tags: android

I have 2 radio buttons inside a radio group.  Right now they are lined up vertically.  I tried putting them in a horizontal container, but it did not worck.

Is there a way to get a radio group of buttons to line up horizontaly?

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioSex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioChats"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chats" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioPlayers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Players" 
        android:checked="true" />

    </RadioGroup>

<Button android:text="Home" 
    android:id="@+id/buthome"
     android:paddingTop="-15dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:text="Players" 
       android:id="@+id/butplayers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/viewActivePlayer" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TedP" 
      android:layout_gravity="right" 
         android:textColor="#fffff109"
    android:textSize="26dip" />
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Add `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `RadioGroup` tag:

```
<RadioGroup
   android:id="@+id/radioSex"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:orientation='horizontal'>
```

Comment: RadioGroup extends LinearLayout, So it inherits the properties of LinearLayout, See [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup)

Answer (score 13):

You can also set this programmatically:

```
myRadioGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```