# Is there a way to make it so radio buttons are drawn horizontally instead of vertical?

Tags: android

On small devices, the ok button does not get drawn in my dialog box.  To save rome, I was wondering if there is a way to make my radio buttons drawn horizontal (so the buttons are on the same row), instead of vertical.  My xml code

```
                  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Auto Play Back"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fffff109"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24px"

             />

          <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioSex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Off" />

</RadioGroup>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Add this into the RadioGroup and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the RadioGroup has an orientation property that you can set.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443492/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-radio-group-be-laid-out-horizontally?rq=1 ??